# remove quotes from returned string of grape api

Tags: html, ruby, thin, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to return raw data/blob from my grape/rest api.

I followed the thread at : https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/412

for a code like :

```
get 'foo' do
  content_type 'text/plain'
  "hello world"
end
```

1)
I used : format 'txt'
- I got quoted text like : "hello world"
no error on the browser though, curl gives Content-Type: text/plain but the quotes are not removed

2)
env['api.format'] = :txt
gives error in browser

3)
content_type :txt, 'text/plain'
gives error in browser wrong number of args

Any other ways to fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use 'body', all that is left to do is to add one line in the API class (above this method):

```
content_type :txt, 'text/plain'
```

So that Grape uses :txt formatter for all endpoints that serve text/plain content

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

```rb
get 'foo' do
  content_type 'text/plain'
  env['api.format'] = :binary
  body 'Stuff here'
end
```

[The documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#api-formats) says:

> env['api.format'] = :binary # there's no formatter for :binary, data will be returned "as is"

So as long as you don't override the `:binary` formatter, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/intridea/grape#sending-raw-or-no-data) you can do the following:

```
class API < Grape::API
  get 'foo' do
    content_type 'text/plain'
    body 'hello world'
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not the single quotes that should do the trick, its `body` that should do it according to the documentation.

Comment: I previously included the incorrect URL. I've updated my answer with the URL I wanted to post, but apparently that didn't work out for you. There's a lot of documentation on that page btw.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any progress on this? Why is such a simple thing so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Using `content_type :txt, 'text/plain'` above the method and using the `body` method worked for me. Here is my code snippet:

`content_type :txt, "text/plain"
  desc "ping pong"
  get "/ping" do
    challenge = params["hub.challenge"]
    challenge = "pong" if challenge.to_s.empty?
    status 200
    body challenge
  end`